# What is the equation for the standard deviation of the set of all odd integers?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, article-writing

I have a set containing all of the odd integers in the integer set. It is denoted by $O=\{2n+1\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I want to write an equation that equals the standard deviation of the set. If I already know that $$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\sum(x_i-\mu)^2}{N}}$$ is the formula for standard deviation, where $\sigma$ represents the standard deviation, $N$ represents the length of the set, $x_i$ represents each value of the set, $\mu$ represents the [population mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_population#Mean) of the set, and the set I have is indefinitely long, then how can I write the equation?

Comment: This makes no sense.  What's $\mu$?  Counting measure on an infinite set doesn't work, you need to define a probability distribution for it.

Comment: Oh, $\mu$ is the symbol for the Greek letter [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(letter)).

Comment: On a countable infinite set distribution CANNOT be uniform.

Comment: @herbsteinberg is correct for classical probability. However, in number-theoretic probability you might define this SD to be the limit of the SDs of increasingly long sequences of odd numbers from $1$ to $2n+1.$ In R, I get increasingly large answers for increasingly long sequences.
For odd numbers up to 99 it's $29.15476$ and for odd numbers up to 999, it's $288.9637.$ Maybe you are supposed to find a way to make sense of that. In R: code `sd(seq(1, 99, by=2))` returns $29.15476$
and `sd(seq(1, 999, by=2))` returns $288.9637.$ These are _samples_ so denom's inside square roots are $n-1.$

Comment: The limit will be infinite.